# How to play a map on skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, steam-workshop

I recently subscribed to 2 things

- A Stanley Paradox (game mode)
- Windfall Island (map)

I would really like to play either of these but I cannot find a way to launch anything like this.  I have mods like `Craftable Lockpicks` and `Faster Vanilla Horses` working fine, but maps/game modes don't.

How can I launch these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the mod itself how it's launched or where it's located.

---

**A Stanley Paradox**

> Head over to Sleeping Giants Inn and read the scroll

*See [the 'Stanley Paradox' description](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/70107/?)*

---

**Windfall Island**

> The island itself is situated just north of Dawnstar but for ease of traval you can quick travel to it but using the console command "coc windfall" without the quotation marks or use the location marker in the in game map to fast travel.

*See [the 'Windfall Island' description](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/22768/?)*